# Dell PERC H310 suporta HDD 4kn?

Tags: disk-controller

Does anyone know if the controller PERC H310 supports HDD 4kN?

Recently I bought the HDD HGST HUS726020ALN610 2TB but when connecting can not configure.

The message PD MGMT:
Capacity: 232.37
State: Blocked

---

Thank you.
With this information better analyzing the scenario we can say that in my case is incompatiblidade (BIOS and PERC Controller).
[image: Disk ID 3 is my new disk of 2TB]

and in detail we can see: Supported = no
[image: Supporte: No]

HD can not be configured and used in the PERC controller.

then connected the SATA port:
Size recognized in the BIOS: 232 GB

After starting the operating system:
HDD Recognized: Yes
Size: 2TB

I will use it as well and I will be more careful when buying new HDD.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is very difficult to understand what you are describing in your post. Please take a few minutes to explain what the problem is, what you have done to try to resolve it and where you are stuck. Then ask a specific question. If you need help, read [ask] in the [help].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.

The Dell PERC H310 is a rebadged "LSI SAS 2008" RAID controller. As the name suggests, it was released around 2008/2009.

The 4K Native specification was completed in 2010, two years after the LSI SAS 2008 (and H310) were initially released. There were no firmware updates released by either LSI or Dell to retroactively enable 4K "Advanced Format" mode. I note that Microsoft didn't support 4K in Windows until Windows 8 and Server 2012 in 2012.

For most use-cases the performance and capacity benefits of 4K formatting are not particularly spectacular and really depend on your whole system stack (drives, controllers, operating system, and running applications) to be specifically designed to benefit - this article from 2010 running Windows 7 shows marginal improvements at-best: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/advanced-format-4k-sector-size-hard-drive,2759.html

In summary: "No, but don't sweat it."

Comment: Ok.
So it must be why only recognizes 232 GB and not 2TB.
Thank you.

Comment: @WellingtonSilva That has nothing to do with Advanced Format. You can have up to a 2TB drive with default-sized clusters: http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/hard-disk-drives-capacity-limits/6/